# Dropdown arrow on Microsoft.com

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, stylesheet

How does Microsoft do the dropdown arrow on their page? I have inspected the CSS and HTML and I dont see how it is done.

[image: see red mark]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a special font character. See style.cssx in a tool like Chrome Dev Tools

```
@media screen and (min-width: 540px)
.dropdown>a:after {
margin-left: .35em;
font-family: "MSHPIconsRegular";
content: '';
font-size: .688em;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When I inspect with Firebug, I see this:

```
.dropdown > a:after {
    content: "";
    font-family: "MSHPIconsRegular";
    font-size: 0.688em;
    margin-left: 0.35em;
}
```

So, as you can see, M$ is adding pseudo-content with `:after` and `content:`.

Comment: this was a new concept to me, I didn't know you could add your own fonts, now I know. Thats why I didnt get it.